# object property is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was working with object properties in javascript and I got stuck with a problem that I couldn't find out. In this javascript program I have created object properties for name and age and I have created getters and setters.

```js
function people(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
    get: function() {
      return age;
    }
  }, {
    set: function(value) {
      if (value < 18) {
        alert("You are below legal age");
      } else {
        age = value;
      }
    }
  })
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    get: function() {
      return name;
    }
  })
}
var pep = new people("John", 22);
document.write(pep);
```

After I crate a object and try to print it I am getting the output as `[object,object]`. But I am able to print the name and age using `pep.name` or `pep.age`. When I try to change the value of age using `pep.age=40` and print it, it displays the old value not the new value.

Comment: Is this the best code formatting you can show us...? It's hard to follow your code!

Comment: Your code has a lot of syntax issues. Are you looking for someone to fix them? You need to ask for concrete issues.

Comment: Please open "Console" tab in the Dev Tools of your browser, you'll see some error messages. They will tell you, what to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just has a bunch of syntax errors. It's always best to run our code through a debugger / syntax check first. Here's your code, reformatted and with correct syntax working fine:

```
function people(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;


    Object.defineProperty(this, 'age', {
        get: function() {
          return age;
        },
        set: function(value) {
            if (value < 18) {
                alert("You are below legal age");
            } else {
                age = value;
            }
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        get: function() {
          return name;
        }
    });
}

var pep = new people("John", 22);
pep.age = 25;
alert(pep.age); //25
```